# 3ds Max BlendedBoxMap support for the Forge Vewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, 3dsmax

We are really interested in adding `BlendingBoxMaps` to certain objects in our model (such as terrain and larger geometry to avoid obvious repeating in the texture).
However, all our test has failed as objects containing `BlendedBoxMap` (see image below) turns black after translated to `SVF`. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

*Update:*
If the above doesn't work. Is there any alternative to BlendedBoxMapping to achieve good looking textures for larger terrain? We are aware that baking the texture onto large mesh gives very blurry results as the SVF translation reduces all larger texture resolutions to 1024x1024 (which seems to be impossible to avoid) and stretches the 1024x1024 texture as much as needed to fit the large object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If materials using BlendedBoxMap fail to correctly appear in the viewer, as a workaround, I would suggest trying to bake your material into a single Bitmat.
Here is an example of how to do so using bake to texture:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-37414F9F-5E33-4B1C-A77F-547D0B6F511A-htm.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes we've tried that but as updated in thr question the baked result unfortunately gets resized (forced?) to 1024x1024 after translated to SVF. This is far too small as the result looks very blurry when it stretches to fit the large object